# Evaluation of `groupBy` in haskell

Tags: haskell

Why does

```
groupBy (>) [-5,-4,5,4,-2,-3,2,3]
```

evaluate to

```
[[-5],[-4],[5,4,-2,-3,2,3]]
```

As `-3` is not greater than `2` shouldn't it group them differently?
I expected the result to be

```
[[-5],[-4],[5,4,-2,-3],[2,3]]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: No, it always calls it on the **first** member of the group. So it compares `-3` with `5`.

Comment: I tried to fix up your formatting. You should indent to format longer code pieces. Backticks are only really good for very small chunks.

Comment: Oh! okay. Thank you for explanation and for the tip about indention.

Comment: What is the point of multiplying each number by 1 before comparing them?

Comment: I multiplied it by 1 while I was trying to understand how `on` works. I have edited the question to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`groupBy :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]` uses the **first member** of the group as reference. So if you write:

```
groupBy eq (x:x2:x3)
```

it will - if `eq x x2` is satisfied, call `eq x x3` to check if `x3` also belongs to the same group. So the calls are:

```
arg1 | arg2 | (>) `on` (*1)
  -5 |   -4 | False
  -4 |    5 | False
   5 |    4 | True
   5 |   -2 | True
   5 |   -3 | True
   5 |    2 | True
   5 |    3 | True
```

We can see this in the [*source code* of `groupBy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/src/Data.OldList.html#groupBy):

> ```
> groupBy                 :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
> groupBy _  []           =  []
> groupBy eq (x:xs)       =  (x:ys) : groupBy eq zs
>                            where (ys,zs) = span (eq x) xs
> ```

As you can see, the `span` takes `eq x` as predicate, and `x` is the first member of the group.

The function probably expects `a -> a -> Bool` to be an **equivalence relation**: an equivalence relation is (1) *reflexive*; (2) *symmetric*; and (3) *transitive*. Your function is not an equivalence relation since it is not reflexive nor symmetric. So you can not (safely) use `groupBy` with an order relation.

Note: `` (>) `on` (*1) `` is equivalent to just `(>)` because `(*1)` will return the same number, you only make the function more specific here to only work on `Num`s, but that is not necessary.

Comment: I wonder if that behavior is guaranteed by the libraries or is an incident of its implementation. The docs do not specify whether `eq` must be an equivalence relation. It just refers to an "equality test". (Maybe one should be conservative and only use an equivalence for `eq`)

Comment: @chi: I agree, it is probably an implementation detail. I added a note that `eq` should be an equivalence relation. Thanks for the feedback.